# cocoa:How Integer type converted to a string type?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

Code can not run
error:too many arguments to method call ,expected 1 ,have 2

```
NSDate *nows =[NSDate date];
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [gregorian components:(NSHourCalendarUnit  | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit) fromDate:nows];
NSInteger hour = [dateComponents hour];
NSInteger minute = [dateComponents minute];
NSInteger second = [dateComponents second];
NSInteger month=[dateComponents month];
NSInteger day=[dateComponents day];
NSLog(@"%lu",day);    

statusItem.image=[NSImage imageNamed:@"status%lu.png",day];

[gregorian release];
```

[image]

Is not trying to type Integer converted to a string type ? what can i do?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

NSImage's "imageNamed" method knows nothing about format strings.

change this:

```
statusItem.image=[NSImage imageNamed:@"status%lu.png",day];
```

to this:

```
statusItem.image=[NSImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"status%lu.png",day]];
```